# TYPO3 / RealURL force GET Parameter for every link

Tags: typo3, typoscript, realurl, typolink

I have the problem to structure a site not just to a language but also do separate the content for different countries. Especially the meta tag for "lang" should be set different for every country. No my idea is to introduce a new GET Parameter "country" and define it as preVar in the real url config.

Now my question. Is there a way to force this GET Parameter in every link which gets rendered with the TypoLink function?

Thanks in advance.

Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching for the [config.linkVars](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#linkvars) option. To set a default for the parameter, you can use [config.defaultGetVars](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#defaultgetvars), or let RealURL do it.